# May the same attribute be specified more than one time in an HTML5 element?

Tags: html, attributes

I am looking now through the HTML5 specification (W3C Recommendation 28 October 2014) and I can not find where there is written whether the same attribute may be specified for an element more than one time. For example sometimes attribute style has a very long value. So a question arises: may it be split in several style attributes for better readability?

Could somebody point to the place in the specification where there is said that it is allowed or not?

EDIT: Also in Section "3.2.5.8 The style attribute" there is written "All HTML elements may have the style content **attribute set**". If the same attribute may be specified at most once then what does words **attribute set** mean in this context?

Comment: I've never seen anything on that either; you can always test it out in a browser.  If you have that many styles, why not use a CSS class?

Comment: @Brian Mains I am reading some book on HTML5 and there are used embedded style attributes with long values. So it is naturally that the question arised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 spec, [**Section 8.2.4.35 - 'Attribute name state'**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state) says:

> When the user agent leaves the attribute name state (and before emitting the tag token, if appropriate), the complete attribute's name must be compared to the other attributes on the same token; if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be removed from the token.

So, to answer your question, it's invalid HTML.

Comment: It'll be better if you provide a link to the spec on w3c.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. Added link.

Comment: @Tryth In  Section 3.2.5.8 The style attribute there is written "All HTML elements may have the style content attribute set". So what does word "set" mean in this context?

Comment: @Vlad The word 'set' means the attribute exists. In effect, it is saying that every tag may have a style attribute.