# HTML Schema - combining multiple spans

Tags: html, schema

I have searched stackoverflow and the web and I can't find an direct answer to this question.

On my website I have added the schema information for the price of an item (see below)

```
    <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      Adults and over 10 years old Presale– <span itemprop="price" content="10.00">
      <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
      <span itemprop="availability">
      <span itemprop="availabilityStarts" content="2017-01-01T00:00">
      <span itemprop="availabilityEnds" content="2017-03-17T23:00">
      <span itemprop="inventoryLevel" content="10000">
      <span itemprop="url" content="http://www.website.com">
      $10</span></span></span></span></span></span></span>
    </span>
```

So as you can see, I have a TON of `<span >` code.  I want to try and reduce this.

I have tested the validation of this snippet via W3C and it validated just fine.

What I am curious about is A) is there a better way, and B) can I just reduce to 1 `<span>` and include all of that in one so it would look like this:

```
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
      <span itemprop="availability" itemprop="availabilityStarts" content="2017-01-01T00:00" itemprop="availabilityEnds" content="2017-03-17T23:00" itemprop="inventoryLevel" content="10000" itemprop="url" content="http://www.website.com">
```

Or am I trying to cram too much in one area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, what you did is fine. However, you currently list the `itemprop` and `content` attributes many times on this single `<span>` element. This [is invalid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458513/962603).

Instead, I recommend using [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

```
<span data-price="10.00"
    data-price-currency="USD"
    data-availability="true"
    data-availability-starts="2017-01-01T00:00"
    data-availability-ends="2017-03-17T23:00"
    data-inventory-level="10000"
    data-url="http://www.example.com"></span>
```

Further reading: [using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.